# JQUERY inArray not matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm tearing my hair out working with [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) and I'm hoping yinz can help.

I have AJAX that pulls down some userIDs from my database. It's JSON-encoded and pulls down as an array. However, when I try to match a value against the array, I always get -1. It never matches.

I've put in a series of alerts to try to figure out what is going on, and I can't for the life of me sort of why it's not working. For sake of argument lets pretend the users it's pulling down are #s 1, 2, and 3. The userids represented in the image collection are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/* some url */",
    success: function (players) {
        $("#userpics img").each(function () {
            var userid = $(this).data("userid");
            alert (players); // 1,2,3
            alert (userid); // 1
            alert ("is array? " + Array.isArray(players)); // true
            alert ("in array? " + $.inArray(userid, players)); // -1
            alert ("in object? " + (userid in players)); // false
            alert ("match? " + (userid == players[0])); // true
        })
   }
});
```

So as you can see, the array being pulled down is displaying as a string in the first alert, but it parses as an array in the third alert. Even when the `userid = 1` and the data pulled down is `["1","2","3"]` it still cannot match with `inArray`. However, when I match `userid == players[0]` it matches.

I am completely stumped.

Comment: do a console.log() of players and you will see why it doesnt work. Hopefully you can print it here to get better help

Comment: Is players an array of strings or an array of numbers?  How about userid?

Comment: What do you get for `(userid === players[0])`? I recommend you stop making assumptions about the datatypes and start making sure they're _exactly_ what you want them to be.  You can use `parseInt` to make sure a var is a number.  You could also try reading the documentation for _jQuery.inArray()_.

Comment: or `$.inArray(userid+"", players)`

Comment: jahroy - I had parseInt originally on the userid declaration. It didn't solve the problem. But your type-testing is definitely on to something. == works, === does not. This must mean the json is pulling down ints as strings, I think.

Comment: _inArray_ is returning zero... Therefore your if statement evaluates to false.  Try reading the documentation (this should always be step 1).  It specifically metions how to deal with the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: jahroy - inArray is returning -1, not 0.

Comment: Ooops... Then it was probably the first thing: the datatypes.  You should only use `parseInt` if you expect your array to contain numbers.

Comment: Any chance _userid_ contains whitespace?

Comment: jahroy - no. The issue turned out to be that PDO turns everything into a string. D'oh. I've been messing around with ways to force PDO to pull everything as an int to no avail. Doing `userid+""` resolves the issue by casting the userid int as a string. it feels wrong, but it's working so that's good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)...

*[jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)* returns the index of the element in the array (if found).

When you search for the first element in the array, the result will be **ZERO**.

Zero evaluates to *false* in JavaScript.

You need to explicitly compare the result of *inArray()* to `-1` to determine whether or not it contains an element.

Use this:

```
if (inArray(val, someArray) !== -1) {
    alert("it's in there...");
}
```

In stead of this:

```
if (inArray(val, someArray)) {
    alert("This won't work for the first element.");
}
```

Comment: You should explicitly check if the return value is not equal to **`-1`**.

Answer (score 0):

Look 's like your comparing  a string with array of numbers..

That might be a reason you are getting this output..

Also check if it is returning a negative index as that suggests the item is not present in the array

```
if( $.inArray(userid, players) > - 1){

    // Item in array
}
```